# kubernetes configmap passing values to spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, configmap

I have a Spring boot configuration class that has a Map of Maps that I want to configure using Kubernetes config map

The configuration class is

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test-property")
public class TestConfig { 
    private Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mapConfig = new HashMap<>();

    private Map<String, Integer> getInnerMap(String key) {
        return mapConfig.getOrDefault(key, emptyMap());
    }
}
```

I am trying to inject the values from the Kubernetes configmap file, but it does not seem to inject the values.

In application.yml I have the below configuration and Spring boot is able to inject it when I run the Spring boot application

```
test-property:
  mapConfig:
    mapKey: 
      innerMapKey: innerMapIntegerValue
```

Is it possible to configure the configmap in Kubernetes to inject a map of maps?

I have tried configuring the values in the configMap like below

```
test-property.mapConfig: |
    property: |
      innerMapKey: innerMapIntegerValue
```

but it does not seem to inject the values into the map as I am always getting back the emptyMap when I try and call getInnerMap

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you using the ConfigMap; how does the Spring application know to read the content from there?

Comment: the configmap is loaded through kubernetes. Single level properties work , this is the only time we are trying to load a map through properties

Comment: Including a [mcve] in the question showing the Kubernetes/Spring wiring could be helpful.  If you can set Spring properties directly in the ConfigMap, it looks like this configuration class would support a property `test-property.map-config.mapKey.innerMapKey`, does setting that directly in the ConfigMap work?

Comment: I had a similar issue, check my own answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019081/spring-boot-3-does-not-load-configmap

This can help also: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/1239