# Spring boot 3 does not load configMap

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes, spring-boot-3

I have a minimalist app with spring boot 3.1.1 and spring cloud 2022.0.4, on EKS with kubernetes 1.27, but unfortunately the config is never loaded from the ConfigMap ...

The app is made of a single file without any configuration or `application.yaml` to serve content from `static` resources:

```
package ch.brw.hive.frontend

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class App

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<App>(*args)
}
```

My gradle project name is `spring-boot-frontend` and the `build.gradle.kts` is:

```
...
springBoot {
  buildInfo()
}
...
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config")
implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all")
...
```

My `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "spring-boot-frontend"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "frontend"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "spring-boot-frontend"
          image: "{{ .Values.frontend.image.registry }}/{{ .Values.frontend.image.name }}:{{ .Values.frontend.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.frontend.image.pullPolicy | quote }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.frontend.resources | nindent 12 }}
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "frontend"
```

My `configMap.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "spring-boot-frontend"
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    server:
      port: 8181
```

My `role.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.fullyQualifiedName }}
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["*"]
    verbs: ["*"]
```

My `roleBinding.yaml` (I use the default service account):

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.fullyQualifiedName }}
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: {{ .Values.fullyQualifiedName }}
  apiGroup: ""
```

The log does not show any error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

2023-08-31T19:54:27.718Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] ch.brw.hive.frontend.AppKt               : Starting AppKt using Java 17.0.8 with PID 1 (/app/classes started by root in /)
2023-08-31T19:54:27.720Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] ch.brw.hive.frontend.AppKt               : The following 1 profile is active: "kubernetes"
2023-08-31T19:54:29.061Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=3d87bae4-72a0-3c9a-ad7b-c5d752a70bf4
2023-08-31T19:54:29.381Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-08-31T19:54:29.391Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-08-31T19:54:29.392Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.10]
2023-08-31T19:54:29.476Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-08-31T19:54:29.479Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1674 ms
2023-08-31T19:54:30.075Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.k.client.KubernetesClientUtils     : Created API client in the cluster.
2023-08-31T19:54:30.308Z  INFO 1 --- [ler-V1Endpoints] i.k.client.informer.cache.Controller     : informer#Controller: ready to run resync & reflector runnable
2023-08-31T19:54:30.308Z  INFO 1 --- [ler-V1Endpoints] i.k.client.informer.cache.Controller     : informer#Controller: resync skipped due to 0 full resync period
2023-08-31T19:54:30.310Z  INFO 1 --- [s.V1Endpoints-1] i.k.c.informer.cache.ReflectorRunnable   : class io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Endpoints#Start listing and watching...
2023-08-31T19:54:30.342Z  INFO 1 --- [els.V1Service-1] i.k.c.informer.cache.ReflectorRunnable   : class io.kubernetes.client.openapi.models.V1Service#Start listing and watching...
2023-08-31T19:54:31.308Z  INFO 1 --- [pool-9-thread-1] s.c.k.c.d.KubernetesDiscoveryClientUtils : Waiting for the cache of informers to be fully loaded..
2023-08-31T19:54:31.309Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.c.k.c.d.KubernetesDiscoveryClientUtils : Cache fully loaded (total 3 services), discovery client is now available
2023-08-31T19:54:31.464Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-08-31T19:54:31.539Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-08-31T19:54:31.564Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] ch.brw.hive.frontend.AppKt               : Started AppKt in 4.674 seconds (process running for 5.105)
```

As you can see the port is never changed to 8181, which should be the case the the `application.yaml` was loaded properly.

I was reading the doc again and again:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#configmap-propertysource

Does anyone have any ideas about what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by adding in my `deployment.yaml`:

```
args: [
  "--spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true"
  "--spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name=spring-boot-frontend",
  "--spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.namespace={{ .Release.Namespace }}"
]
```

This was poorly documented ...

Comment: spring-cloud-k8s contributor here. these kind of things are usually best asked on the github project forum, as an issue for example. if you think this is poorly documented, we can definitely improve! but first open an issue there with a reproducible sample and we can take a look, thank you

Comment: Eugene, thank you for passing by, I think that if you provide concrete github repos with working samples it's gonna help a lot in the doc, especially to understand the use of the `bootstrap.enabled`. But it's a great piece of code in general when we understand how it's working.

Comment: we have a lot of integration projects where there are real examples of things working, otherwise the build would fail :) granted, your pain is heard loud and clear, and I do plan to make youtube videos with real repos on how things work. Something like [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/1461), but with a real sample and live coding. We will get there...